# Show action with more than two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an invoice model that has many_invoice items

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :inverse_of => :invoices
  attr_accessible :approved_by, :due_date, :invoice_date, :reading_ids, :terms, :customer_id, :customer, :status

  validates :invoice_date, presence: true
  validates :due_date, presence: true
  validates :customer, presence: true
  has_many :invoice_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_items
end
```

Invoice Items Model

```
class InvoiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  attr_accessible :amount, :description, :rate, :tax_amount
end
```

I now have a show action in my Invoices_controller

```
def show
@invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
end
end
```

I want to be able to show the invoice_items like description, tax amount and rate in the show page for the invoices however, it is giving me quite a challenge. Do I have to create a partial in there that deals with the invoice items? Below is my show page

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
    <h3> Customer Invoices </h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Invoice ID </th>
      <th>Customer Name </th>
      <th>Invoice Date </th>
      <th>Due Date </th>
      <th>Amount</th>     
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= @invoice.customer.name %></td>
    <td><%= @invoice.invoice_date %></td>
    <td><%= @invoice.due_date %></td>   
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a partial is not a must, but you could do this in either way

**1 - with out a partial**

```
in your show.html.erb

#your invoice code
<% invoice_items = @invoice.invoice_items %>
<% invoice_items.each to |invoice_item|%>
<tr>
  <td><%= invoice_item.amount%></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

**2 ) with  a partial**

```
in your show.html.erb

#your invoice code
    <% invoice_items = @invoice.invoice_items %>
    <% invoice_items.each to |invoice_item|%>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <%= render :partial => 'invoice_item', :locals => {:item => invoice_item}%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

 in your _invoice_item.html.erb

 <%= item.name %>
```

HTH

Comment: You are rendering the partial within the <td> tag, that is not correct. You should put the <td> tags in the partial itself.

Comment: hi @cih I dont see a problem with in the td tag as long as the partial itself has the correct formatting, in the above case, partial will have a text, and you could use even a table inside the td

Comment: Hi @sameera207 I guess but don't know why you would want to nest a table within a table in that case. Also in your without a partial example is it necessary to declare an invoice_items variable, do you just find this more verbose? It seems like an unnecessary line of code to me.

Comment: Hi @cih, I think having nested table is a designer issue, and there is no correct or incorrect way of doing it. and yes I agree with you .. invoice_items can be/should be removed :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a partial to keep things tidy but there is no reason you couldn't do this in your show view template.

```
<% @invoice.invoice_items.each do |item| %>
 <td><%= item.amount %></td>
 <td><%= item.description %></td>
 # etc
<% end %>
```

The invoice items are related to the `@invoice` object that you have in your view therefore you can access the invoices `invoice_items`.